# Select subset of data in column of Excel table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a table with a few columns: Date, Person, Category, Result.

I would like to select all data in Table[Result] subject to Table[Category]. So starting at the first entry and proceeding through the table, if the value in Category is a specific value ("A" "donkeys" "whatever"), take the data in Result and Date as a pair.

What I'd like to do is have a Series for a chart, that takes all the results for said category and plots the date on the x axis and the result on the y axis.

It seems like it shouldn't be impossible, but 2 hours of googling and I'm nowhere. Please don't ask why the system is set up in such a stupid way, it's just an immutable fact.

Answer (score 0):

You'll prob need to make a macro for this if you're specifically looking for a way to dynamically generate the list.